# Passing 2 values into constructor where one is generated from the other in Python

Tags: python

I have some class, lets say
`NT = collections.namedtuple('NT', 'v1, v2, v3, v4')`
And I have 2 functions that return some value, where one function takes the value returned by another function. A simple example:

```
def fun1():
    return random.random()

def fun2(x):
    # Takes return value of fun1
    return random.random() * x
```

Those return values will be used for constructor's arguments `v2` and `v3`.
I want to create some collection of these objects (let's say a set). This can be done these ways:

```
s1 = set()
for _ in range(3):
    f1 = fun1()
    f2 = fun2(f1)
    s1.add(NT(1, f1, f2, 1))


s2 = {NT(1, *(lambda x: (x, fun2(x)))(fun1()), 1) for _ in range(3)}


def fun3():
    f1 = fun1()
    return f1, fun2(f1)

s3 = {NT(1, *fun3(), 1) for _ in range(3)}


s4 = {NT(1, *[k for j in ((i, fun2(i)) for i in (fun1(),)) for k in j], 1) for _ in range(3)}


# chain is itertools.chain
s5 = {NT(1, *chain(*chain((i, fun2(i)) for i in (fun1(),))), 1) for _ in range(3)}
```

I think the first option is most readable and fourth one is least readable. Also, they are arranged from fastest to slowest.

Are there more readable ways than solutions 2, 4 and 5 that can be written within a comprehension? Are there other ways to write it?
I'm asking solely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

For god's sake, make a constructor!

If there's some reason you need this to be a `namedtuple` instead of the more full-featured class, then a simple function will do:

```
def make_NT():
    f1 = fun1()
    f2 = fun2(f1)
    return NT(1, f1, f2, 1)
```

but otherwise I'd rather see this be a full `class`

```
class NT(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v1 = 1
        self.v2 = fun1()
        self.v3 = fun2(self.v2)
        self.v4 = 1
```

and either way, this makes the set comprehension easy.

```
results = {make_NT() for _ in range(3)}
# or
results = {NT() for _ in range(3)}
```

---

Note that, of the above, I would consider any approach but #1 incorrect. There's simply no reason to slap that much illegible garbage together to save 4 lines of code.

Comment: I totally agree. Was playing around with coming up with solutions, that's why other examples. I didn't want a full featured class because I had around 10 namedtuples inside my class and didn't need anything but storing the values (generating fake data to fill DB).

Comment: @Szymon Might not be bad to write a `staticmethod` inside your `Row` class to generate that test data for you, though YMMV. In the db-driven apps I've written I've included a method in my database API to put the database in a known state, test it, then rollback.

Comment: (though things like this are why I'm growing to love functional languages. In Haskell this is just `let (b, c) = fun1 >>> id &&& fun2 in NT 1 b c 1`, though in fairness handling the randomness becomes ***massively*** more headachey)

Comment: It was just a one-time small project that generated INSERT queries for my DB classes at University (didn't want to come up and type hundreds of INSERT queries by hand). As I said, this question was more out of curiosity and learning about how to do it when I'll need something similar in production, making it readable, not saving a few lines of code. Thanks for your answers!